# Free 3D pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers

I have a structure GLOBE which contains several parameters for each lat lon cell on the globe.
I have a triple pointer as follows:

```
data->map = (struct GLOBE ***)malloc_2d(NROWS, NCOL, sizeof(struct GLOBE *));

struct GLOBE {
  double *var;
};
```

where malloc_2d is a custom function to allocate 2d arrays defined below. map can iterate over all the GLOBE's.

```
void** malloc_2d (size_t nrows, size_t ncols, int elementsize) {
size_t i;
void ** ptr;
if ( (ptr = (void**)malloc(nrows * sizeof(void *))) == NULL ) {
  fprintf(stderr, "malloc_2d: out of memory\n");
  exit(1);
}
if ( (ptr[0] = malloc(nrows * ncols * elementsize)) == NULL ) {
  fprintf(stderr, "malloc_2d: out of memory\n");
  exit(1);
}

for (i=1; i<nrows; i++) 
  ptr[i] = (char*)ptr[0] + i * ncols * elementsize;
  return ptr;
```

}

GLOBE has other dynamically allocated 1D and 2D arrays(e.g. double *var). So when I have to deallocate all the GLOBE's and the dynamically allocated memory within each GLOBE, I am running into errors.

Specifically, I try:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < data->n_lat; i++)
    for(size_t i = 0; i < data->n_lat; i++) {
        free(data->map[i][j]->var);

free(data->map);
```

However, this does not seem to work. What should I change?
thanks!

Comment: You'll need to post more code here, including the definition of the `GLOBE` structure & the implementation of the `malloc_2d` array. Your code ... "feels strange" ...

Comment: Modified code to include definition of malloc_2d and GLOBE

Answer (score 0):

The `malloc_2d()` (copy-paste?) function seems to be correctly written, but the rest of the code posted here is just complete nonsese ...

I'll post here a working example of something similar that you wanted to do, using the enter code here `malloc_2d()`. I suggest to you to play around with it, until you catch the base idea of the pointers in C.

Also, feel free to ask (clear) questions about the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NROWS 8
#define NCOL 6

struct GLOBE {
  double **var;
};

void** malloc_2d (size_t nrows, size_t ncols, int elementsize)
{
        // code posted
}

void free_2d (void ** ptr, size_t n_rows)
{
    int i;

    // free the "big part"
    free(ptr[0]);

    // free the array of pointers to the rows
    free(ptr);
}

int main()
{
    struct GLOBE gl;
    int i, j;

    gl.var = (double **)malloc_2d(NROWS, NCOL, sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < NROWS; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < NCOL; ++j) {
            gl.var[i][j] = i * j;
            printf("%0.1f ", gl.var[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free_2d((void **)gl.var, NROWS);

    return 0;
}
```